# Should shops be open at all times?

Tags: tiny-tower

I recently started playing *Tiny Tower*. I only have a few shops at the moment, but I do my best to keep them open at all times by keeping them stocked. The only problem I seem to notice is that my bitizens often make comments such as, "It feels like (x) shop never closes!"

I know that if the shops close, I lose money. However:

**Will my bitizens be happier if I let shops close? Do they even get time off?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The great things about bitizens is that they never seem to need to sleep.  Thankfully you don't have to manage your bitizens personal concerns in this game, as the focus is the tower.  Your bitizens will work 24/7 without any loss of productivity, so long as you can keep your shops stocked.  So, yes, shops should be open at all times.

If you see them complaining in the Bitbook, I think that's just the developers way of adding some personality into the game.  :)  The only way to make a bitizen happy in the game is to employ them in their dream job.  Failing that, until their dream job opens in your tower, best practice is to match them with the area that they are highest in according to their profile.  They will at least remain content until such time as their dream job opens and you reassign them.  So long as you can match them with a job of interest level 5 or greater, they will be content.  Anything less than 5 and they will be unhappy in their job.

Comment: And in addition, I've never seen any in-game consequence of having unhappy bitizens (other than the reduced discounts on restocking). I'm pretty sure the sad-ok-happy faces are purely to help the player see good a match the job is.

Answer (score 4):

Bitizens happiness is tied exclusively to what job they have, if it is what they are good at or not and if it is there dream job.

The Tinybook is mostly just fun observations.

So yes keep your stores fully stocked.